# Mutex implementation and signaling

Tags: c++, c, mutex, implementation

When a mutex is already locked by T1, and T2 tries to lock it, what is the process for T2?

I think it goes something like this:

> -T2 tries to lock, fails, maybe spinlocks a bit, then calls yield...
>   -T2 is scheduled for execution a couple of times, tries to lock fails, yields...
>   -Eventually T1 unlocks, T2 is scheduled for execution and manages to lock the mutex...

Does T1 unlocking explicitly signal to the scheduler or other threads that the mutex is unlocked? Or does it just unlock, and leave the scheduler to schedule blocked threads when it feels suitable to do so (aka scheduler has no notion of blocked threads and doesn't treat them as special)?

Comment: `I think` the mutual exclusion principle guarantees that no 2 or more threads enter the critical section at the same time. Now, whether you have a queue for threads that are trying to lock the mutex or you just do a busy-wait till a mutex is free is dependent on how you implement it and what are your needs for mutex. For example, `mutex` in RTOS like VxWorks implement priority ceiling protocol, which you may not need in general purpose OS (GPOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: yes, perhaps...

This is implementation details, and it's rather difficult to say without at the very least knowing which operating system you are talking about. Typically, the unlocking of a mutex will only mark the waiting thread as "runnable", but not (necessarily) invoke the scheduler at that time - and even if the scheduler is called, it doesn't mean that T2 will be the next thread to run.

In Linux, the code enters the `mutex_unlock()` which checks if there is any waiting task (by checking if the lock-count is less than zero - it starts at 1 for unlocked, a single lock-request gets it to zero, a further attempt to lock will make it negative). If there is a further waiting process, it calls a "slow path unlock", which via a couple of redirection functions to allow implementation details, ends up in [`__mutex_unlock_common_slowpath`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/mutex.c#L307) - a few lines further down, there is a call to `wake_up_process` which eventually ends up in [`try_to_wake_up`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/sched/core.c#L1429) - which essentially just queues the task as "ready to run", and then calls the scheduler (via several layers of functions!)

Comment: so you are saying that on linux thread that blocks is marked an not runnable(so sched wont schedule it before it is marked as runable)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That assumes you are using the kernel mutex tho', which may not be what, for example, pthread_mutex implements.

Comment: very good answer... btw without me bothering you much ... can you quickly say if futex differs from this in some significat way.

Comment: I had a quick look at the `futex` code, and it looks quite different, and is a much larger functionality in the kernel...

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your operating system. I've seen just spinning, spinning with `yield`, general purpose condition variables in the kernel, userland controlled scheduling and specialized locking primitives with kernel support.

Spinning and spinning with `yield` have terrible performance. Theoretically userland controlled scheduling (see [Scheduler activations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduler_activations)) should have the best performance, but as far as I know no one has ever made it work properly in all cases. General purpose condition variables in the kernel and specialized locking primitives with kernel support should perform more or less the same with [futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) in Linux as the best example of the latter.

There are situations where spinning can have better performance. In Solaris some locking primitive in the kernel has an adaptive mode where the lock spins as long as the process holding the lock is running on a different cpu. If the lock owner sleeps or gets preempted the lock waiter also goes to sleep. In other kernels there are classes of locks where the lock owner can't be preempted or sleep when holding the lock, so in those cases spinning works well too. In general though, especially in userland, spinning has such horrible degenerate cases (the spinning process spins until it gets preempted to let the lock owner run) that it's very bad for performance. Notice that specialized locking primitives like `futex` could implement optimizations like this, something that general purpose condition variables normally can't.

Comment: nice A, but "Spinning and spinning with yield have terrible performance" should be qualified... I can imagine scenarios of low contention and low amount of work under lock where spinlocks are fast.

Comment: ALL locks are (quite) efficient when there is no contention. Well designed locking methods are ALSO efficient when there is high contention. It also depends on the number of processors available - a "spinning" wait is terrible on a single processor system, because the other thread that is currently holding the lock will not get to run, and T2 is using all the CPU to check if T1 who isn't getting to run has released the lock - that is pretty useless usage of CPU-time.

Comment: @Mats I was thinking about multicore system, but ofc I agree with you for single core.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have following scenario:

```
 1. T1 got M1. M1 locked.
 2. T2 tries to get M1 and gets blocked as M1 is locked.
 3. T3 tries to get M1 and gets blocked as M1 is locked.
 4. ...some time later...
 5. T1 unlocks M1.*
 6. T2 got M1.
 7. T3 is unblocked and tries to get M1 but is blocked again as T2 got M1 first.
```

*The system call, **unlock**, should **notify all** blocked **tasks/processes/threads** which are blocked on the mutex's **lock call**. They are then **scheduled** to execute. That does not mean they are executed as there might be already someone in execution. As others state it depends on the implementation how is that done. If you really want to learn this well I'd recommend this [**book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013230998X)